# How to detect if I'm using an undocumented api in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, undocumented-behavior

I'd like to figure out if I'm using undocumented api's in my app. Are there certain hallmarks or patterns that I can look out i.e., if I use code in my project from a website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before submitting an app to Apple, you can use the Xcode tools to validate your code.

The Apple documentation says:

> In the iOS 5 development tools, it is possible to extract APIs used by
>   an application and have them checked for use of private APIs. This
>   option is offered when you validate your application for app
>   submission.

Also, you could use [Deploymate](http://www.deploymateapp.com) to detect unavailable API usage during development.